# Pass Step Function variable to AWS Glue Job Not Working

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to pass an AWS Step Function variable to a Glue Job parameter, similar to this:
[aws-passing-job-parameters-value-to-glue-job-from-step-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379306/pass-variables-in-aws-step-functions)

However, this is not working for me. The glue job error message indicates that it's getting the passed variable name--not the actual value of the variable. Here's my Step Function code:

```
{
  "Comment": "Converts CSV files to parquet for a date range.",
  "StartAt": "ConfigureCount",
  "States": {
    "ConfigureCount": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": {
        "start": 201601,
        "end": 201602,
        "index": 201601
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.iterator",
      "Next": "Iterator"
    },
    "Iterator": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789:function:date-iterator",
      "ResultPath": "$.iterator",
      "Next": "IsCountReached"
    },
    "IsCountReached": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.iterator.continue",
          "BooleanEquals": true,
          "Next": "ConvertToParquet"
        }
      ],
      "OutputPath": "$.iterator",
      "Default": "Done"
    },
    
    "ConvertToParquet": {
      "Comment": "Your application logic, to run a specific number of times",
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "convert-to-parquet",
        "Arguments": {
          "--DATE_RANGE": "$.iterator.index"
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.iterator.index",
      "Next": "Iterator"
    },
    "Done": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

The step "Iterator"step  is calling a Lambda called "date-iterator" which returns JSON similar to the following:

```
{
  "start": "201601",
  "end": "201602",
  "index": "201601"
}
```

This was based on this article, so that I can loop through values: [Iterating a Loop Using Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html)

My Step Function fails, saying "$.iterator.index" is not a valid date.

How do I pass this value, and not the variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Amazon States Language (https://states-language.net/spec.html):

> If any field within the Payload Template (however deeply nested) has a name ending with the characters ".$", its value is transformed according to rules below and the field is renamed to strip the ".$" suffix.

Based on that adding `.$` should solve your issue:

```
"Parameters": {
        "JobName": "convert-to-parquet",
        "Arguments": {
          "--DATE_RANGE.$": "$.iterator.index"
        }
      },
```